# adb can't find Galaxy S3 Android 4.3

Tags: android, windows-7, android-studio, adb, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I update android version of my Galaxy S3 to Android 4.3.

I have activated the developer mode by clicking Build Number and also checked in USB Debugging. I am using Windows 7 and Android Studio.

I have gone through various answer addressing same problem but none of them helped.

How can I install application directly to my device or debug using adb etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into device manager and uninstalled SAMSUNG Android USB Composite Device and ensured  to check the box 'delete driver software'.   Now the device will have a exclamiation mark etc ..i right click and installed the driver again (refresh copy) ...this finally made the adb acknowledge my phone as an emulator.

to install [drivers](http://androidsecurity.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/install-google-nexus-4-adb-usb-drivers-on-windows-android-studio/)

Answer (score 3):

I just went to the Samsung site and installed usd drivers of my S3 (SGH-I747). Everything is working fine. Device detected by ADB.

Link for [S3 drivers](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SGH-I747MBBATT)

Answer (score 2):

you need to check whether your adb software is correctly install or not, you can download adb installer from  http://adbdriver.com/downloads/ run it as a administrator and install adb driver.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the only thing that worked was to install the latest android adt bundle from here.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Once I connected my phone via USB, I was prompted to allow for debugging mode.